# After connecting Azure Data Factory to a different repo none of the json objects are visible in the portal for branches other than master

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

We decided to consolidate projects and repos into one project in Azure DevOps. This meant cloning the repository in the new project. One of those projects is an Azure Data Factory that has multiple topic branches. We followed the [disconnecting the Azure Data Factory instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#switch-to-a-different-git-repository) from the old Git repo and connecting it to the new Git repo guidance. I selected import all objects from the `master` branch as this is our collaboration branch.

When navigating to the 'Author' tab in Azure Data Factory **the only branch that has any objects visible** is the `master` branch. I opened the repo in Azure DevOps to see whether the topic branches contain JSON, they do.

We have multiple branches that are being developed in parallel and require that the objects defined in these branches be included. The obvious *solution* is to merge branches and recreate the topic branches. The problem with this is that some work is partially complete and therefore should not be included in the collaboration branch.

I also waited 30 minutes to see if there was a delay between making the connection and all objects being read from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you confirm that the structure of your new repository's master branch matches that of the feature branches where the resources are not loaded exactly? For example, if the json files are valid and in the same folder structure in the feature branches and the master branch, ADF UI will be able to load them.

"I opened the repo in Azure DevOps to see whether the topic branches contain JSON, they do." One likely explanation is that the git connection is configured to a subdirectory of the repository, ex. /adf, but the feature branches are not using this subdirectory. The solution in this case would be to move the files into the correct folder.

To clarify a few points, once you disconnected and reconnected to the new repository, the connection with the old repository is completely removed and ADF will only use the new git connection to fetch files. Also, the [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#author-with-azure-repos-git-integration) in the second part of your post does not seem relevant to your issue.

Comment: I agree regarding your comment on the note, I was clutching at straws and going slightly mad. Regarding your other points I will investigate and reply asap @jmcallister.

Comment: It was indeed the root setting in Data Factory not matching the repo structure. I changed '/' to '/adf'. I appreciate the answer.